# Master Detail Scaling detail background color XAMARIN

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, background-color, master-detail

I have a master detail page and I scaled the detail page, which is by the way a navigation page and the following image is the result. Now I want to change the background color (white) to the same color as the master page. How can I achieve this? I tried setting the background color of the MasterDetail page, the background color of the detail page and still no luck.

[image: Master shown]

This is how I basically set the master detail pages:

```
Master = new MenuPage() { Title = "menu.", Icon = "ic_hamburger.png" };

             navpage = new TransparentNavBarPage(new ExploreNewUserPage());
            navpage.barColor = Color.FromHex("#0197ED");
            navpage.BarTextColor = Color.White;
            Detail = navpage;
```

and this is how I scaled the navigation page when master is presented:

```
if (IsPresented)
{
    navpage.ScaleTo(0.8, 250, Easing.CubicIn);
}
else
{
    navpage.ScaleTo(1, 250, Easing.CubicIn);


}
```

Comment: Can you add some code to show how you are trying to do it now?

Comment: @Sanne updated my question.

Comment: Hi @MetaSnarf, I know that this is the old post, but I need to ask you, where did you put ScaleTo option? Are you waiting for some event?